# time and space complexity of finding combination (nCr)

Tags: algorithm, combinations, complexity-theory

Whats the worst case time and space complexity of different algorithms to find combination i.e. nCr
Which algorithm is the best known solution in terms of time/space complexity?

Comment: Do you mean finding the actual combinations, or the number of combinations?

Comment: Finding the number as well as actual combinations

Comment: The time and space complexity of generating all combinations is: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Combination.html. The time and space complexity of finding the **number** of combinations is `O(1)`.

Answer (score -1):

`O(n!)` is the time complexity to generate all combinations one by one.

To find how many combinations are there, we can use this formula:

```
nCr = n! / ( r! * (n-r)! )
```

As @beaker mentioned, this count can be calculated in `O(1)` time (i.e., constant time).

Comment: How can you find nCr in O(1)? because you need to find n! in O(1) in that case.

Comment: @Naveen this is a basic combinatorical rule... sees Beaker link in the comments

Comment: @Aviv What do you mean? Who can calculate N! in O(1)? It's O(N) by nature.

Comment: The best you can do is calculating nCr in `O(r)` time.