# Find number of combinations, nCr in O(1)

Tags: c, math, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

Is there a way to find the number of combinations (not the actual combinations), in O(1)? I read an answer here -  [time and space complexity of finding combination (nCr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979545/time-and-space-complexity-of-finding-combination-ncr/). The answer says that it takes O(n!) to find the actual combinations but only takes O(1) to find the number of such combinations. I couldn't understand how it can be done. Please explain me how to do that in O(1). Here, O(1) is time complexity.

[edit]:The main problem I'm having is how to implement n! in O(1).

Comment: Generate a look-up table on the fly.

Comment: From scratch you can't calculate n! in O(1). May be the post talks about finding ncr after storing the factorial values

Comment: You can find an *approximate* factorial with [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this is even possible?

Comment: @templatetypedef No I don't have any strong reason to believe that. It was just that two people said the same thing on the link I mentioned, so anyway this is the place to ask it if this is possible.

Comment: I am almost positive that information is incorrect.

Comment: It can be in O(1) for a limited input range given a lookup-table of either log-factorials (log(n!) for 0,1,...,n, linear in size) or a lookup-table of the precomputed nCr results (quadratic in size).

Comment: This question requires heavy editing. Please carefully state if you are talking about time and/or space requirements whenever you write O(.). Also, *none* of the current answers address that you will run into overflow *very* quickly, so you might need some additional code to handle arbitrary large numbers, like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Please check the below `C` program. It takes `n` and `r` as input and calculates **<sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub>** value:

```
int main(){
    int n, r;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &r);

    /*
    *  nCr = n! / !(n-r) / !(r)
    *      = n * n-1 * n-2 * .... * 1 / (n-r * n-r-1 * .. * 1) / 
    *           (r * r-1 * ... * 1)
    *      = n * n-1 * n-2 * n-r+1 / (r * r-1 * ... * 1)
    *      
    */

    int result = 1;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<r; i++){
        result *= (n-i);    // n * n-1 * n-2 * .... * n-(r-1)
        result /= (i+1);    // r * r-1 * ... * 1
    }

    /*  The loop is going to run only r times for any n
     *  Time to calculate nCr : O(r)
     *  Space complexity: O(1)
    */

    printf("Result of C(%d, %d) = %d", n, r, result);

    return 0;
}
```

**To calculate it, the loop runs only for 'r' times.**

Hence, *time complexity to calculate nCr value is `O(r)`*
*But space complexity is `O(1)`*

I guess you must have been confused with these two complexity orders. Hope, it helps you.

Comment: Maybe you are right, the person who answered on the link I mentioned got confused in time and space so he specifically wrote it as time complexity and confused me also.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to calculate `n!` in constant time, why not use Stirling's Approximation?

`n! \approx sqrt(2 * pi * n) * (n / e)^n`

or in `C`:

`pow( n, n ) * exp( -n ) * sqrt( 2.0 * PI * n );`

I think this will get you the closest to constant time, the actual run time of each of those operations is architecture dependent.

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

https://github.com/ankurp/C-Algorithms/blob/master/factorial/fact.c

Answer (score 0):

The run-time complexity of nCr can only be in O(1) if the computing platform you use computes n! in O(1). On a standard computer, this is not the case.

But we can use the fact that exp(n) and log(n) is usually [an O(1) operation for IEEE doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7317571/1647737) and [implement an approximation of log(n!)](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/08/16/how-to-compute-log-factorial/) - based on Stirling's approximation - in O(1):

```
logf(n) = log(n!) = (n – 0.5) * log(n) – n + 0.5 * log(2 * PI) + 1/(12 * n)
```

If we combine this with a lookup-table for log(n!) for n ≤ 255 we will still have at least 14 significant figures and we can compute a very good approximation of nCr as follows:

```
binomial(n, r) = exp(logf(n) - logf(n - r) - logf(r))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ajeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37777743/4109758) should be accepted, but I think it can be improved to `Min(O(r),O(n-r))` which is still `O(r)` if reduced.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        // choose smaller one
        if (n - r < r) { 
            r = n - r;
            System.out.printf("Change %d to %d\n", n - r, r);
        }
        /*
         * nCr  = n! / ((n-r)! * (r)! )
         *      = (n * n-1 * n-2 * .... * 1) / ( (n-r * n-r-1 * .. * 1) * (r * r-1 * ... * 1) )
         *      = (n * n-1 * n-2 * n-r+1) / (r * r-1 * ... * 1)
         */

        int result = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            result *= (n - i); // n * n-1 * n-2 * .... * n-(r-1)
            result /= (i + 1); // r * r-1 * ... * 1
        }

        /*
         * The loop is going to run only r times or (n-r) times for any n Time to calculate nCr : Min ( O(r) , O(n-r) )
         * Space complexity: O(1)
         */
        System.out.printf("Result of C(%d, %d) = %d", n, r, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some of the use cases, it might be best to precompute all the answers in O(n^2) by generating pascal's triangle, so that the queries are O(1).

Other times you just have to calculate n! one by one so the complexity would be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

For smaller inputs, perhaps NOT doing divisions or factorials at all ? - A really trivial piece of summation code is all that it takes to rapidly print out Pascal's triangle.

Obviously this solution isn't that scalable if you need `millions nCr millions`, but for combo parameters more commonly encountered,
e.g.

---

```
      ( 538 )
     nCr
      ( 270 )
```

It probably takes less time to just print out the number of rows and columns you need than trying to go through the multiple nested loops to figure out which numbers you need to keep, which ones to throw away, and how many shifts or trailing zeros you need at the very end.

With most of the time savings stemming from using multiple variables to retain state information in an accumulation chain in lieu of looping through an array/list,

trading off theoretical propriety in favor of practical simplicity.

```
jot 25 | 

mawk '($14 = ______________ += $13 = _____________ += \
       $12 =   ____________ += $11 = ___________   += \
       $10 =     __________ +=  $9 = _________     += \
        $8 =       ________ +=  $7 = _______       += \
        $6 =         ______ +=  $5 = _____         += \
        $4 =           ____ +=  $3 = ___           += \
        $2 =             __ +=  $1 )^_'
```

---

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55 66 78 91 105 120
4 10 20 35 56 84 120 165 220 286 364 455 560 680
5 15 35 70 126 210 330 495 715 1001 1365 1820 2380 3060
6 21 56 126 252 462 792 1287 2002 3003 4368 6188 8568 11628
7 28 84 210 462 924 1716 3003 5005 8008 12376 18564 27132 38760
8 36 120 330 792 1716 3432 6435 11440 19448 31824 50388 77520 116280
9 45 165 495 1287 3003 6435 12870 24310 43758 75582 125970 203490 319770
10 55 220 715 2002 5005 11440 24310 48620 92378 167960 293930 497420 817190
11 66 286 1001 3003 8008 19448 43758 92378 184756 352716 646646 1144066 1961256
12 78 364 1365 4368 12376 31824 75582 167960 352716 705432 1352078 2496144 4457400
13 91 455 1820 6188 18564 50388 125970 293930 646646 1352078 2704156 5200300 9657700
14 105 560 2380 8568 27132 77520 203490 497420 1144066 2496144 5200300 10400600 20058300
15 120 680 3060 11628 38760 116280 319770 817190 1961256 4457400 9657700 20058300 40116600
16 136 816 3876 15504 54264 170544 490314 1307504 3268760 7726160 17383860 37442160 77558760
17 153 969 4845 20349 74613 245157 735471 2042975 5311735 13037895 30421755 67863915 145422675
18 171 1140 5985 26334 100947 346104 1081575 3124550 8436285 21474180 51895935 119759850 265182525
19 190 1330 7315 33649 134596 480700 1562275 4686825 13123110 34597290 86493225 206253075 471435600
20 210 1540 8855 42504 177100 657800 2220075 6906900 20030010 54627300 141120525 347373600 818809200
21 231 1771 10626 53130 230230 888030 3108105 10015005 30045015 84672315 225792840 573166440 1391975640
22 253 2024 12650 65780 296010 1184040 4292145 14307150 44352165 129024480 354817320 927983760 2319959400
23 276 2300 14950 80730 376740 1560780 5852925 20160075 64512240 193536720 548354040 1476337800 3796297200
24 300 2600 17550 98280 475020 2035800 7888725 28048800 92561040 286097760 834451800 2310789600 6107086800
25 325 2925 20475 118755 593775 2629575 10518300 38567100 131128140 417225900 1251677700 3562467300 9669554100
```

---

```
1     1     1      1       1        1        1         1          1
2     3     4      5       6        7        8         9         10
3     6    10     15      21       28       36        45         55
4    10    20     35      56       84      120       165        220
5    15    35     70     126      210      330       495        715

6    21    56    126     252      462      792      1287       2002
7    28    84    210     462      924     1716      3003       5005
8    36   120    330     792     1716     3432      6435      11440
9    45   165    495    1287     3003     6435     12870      24310
10   55   220    715    2002     5005    11440     24310      48620

11   66   286   1001    3003     8008    19448     43758      92378
12   78   364   1365    4368    12376    31824     75582     167960
13   91   455   1820    6188    18564    50388    125970     293930
14  105   560   2380    8568    27132    77520    203490     497420
15  120   680   3060   11628    38760   116280    319770     817190

16  136   816   3876   15504    54264   170544    490314    1307504
17  153   969   4845   20349    74613   245157  <[735471]> <-------- 24 nCr 8
18  171  1140   5985   26334   100947   346104   1081575    3124550
19  190  1330   7315   33649   134596   480700   1562275    4686825
20  210  1540   8855   42504   177100   657800   2220075    6906900

21  231  1771  10626   53130   230230   888030   3108105   10015005
22  253  2024  12650   65780   296010  1184040   4292145   14307150
23  276  2300  14950   80730   376740  1560780   5852925   20160075
24  300  2600  17550   98280   475020  2035800   7888725   28048800
25  325  2925  20475  118755   593775  2629575  10518300   38567100
```

It's reasonably speedy too -

- `99,999 rows :: 0.627 secs`
- `999,999 rows :: 6.910 secs`

  ```
  pascal9:  515MiB 0:00:06 [74.8MiB/s] [74.8MiB/s] [ <=> ]
  ( jot 999999 | gawk -Mbe ; ) 

  6.99s user 0.08s system 102% cpu 6.910 total
  0270dd14bcdfba3279dfd0e9f998f835  stdin
  ```